# Strange issue regarding procedural textures

Tags: texturing, procedural

I am fairly new to this software and have been experimenting with the interface for the past month. Recently I wanted to create an object with a voronoi texture but something strange is happening. The texture splits in half in inverts the 2nd half. I have looked up online to have found nothing discussing this problem. The normals on the object are all fine and I have even pulled up a new file just to test it. Here are some screenshots of what is happening. I'm sure the answer is fairly simple most likely a setting I accidentally activated. Thank you.[image]

Comment: I think it would help if folks could see your node-tree

Comment: This is a default UV sphere I made in a new file and the node tree is just the principled BDSF, the material output, and the voronoi texture plugged into displacement.

Comment: Did you make sure to add a Displacement node between the texture and Displacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to connect the texture through the height input of a displacement node first - see below:

[image]

Comment: Yes that was the problem. As I said earlier I was sure I would be something simple. Thank you for such quick responses.